# Show that $A$ is totally unimodular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, vectors, determinant

A family of sets is nested if for any two members $A$ and $B$ we have that $A\subseteq B$, $B\subseteq A$ or $A\cap B =\emptyset$.

**Exercise:** Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a nested family of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and let $A$ be the matrix whose rows are the characteristic vectors of the sets in $\mathcal{F}$. Show that $A$ is totally unimodular.

*What I've tried:* I believe that characteristic vector means indicator vector in this exercise. That means that we have $$A = \begin{bmatrix}a_{11} &a_{12} & \dots &a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \ldots &\vdots\\
\vdots& \vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\
a_{m1}&a_{m2}&\ldots & a_{mn} \end{bmatrix}$$ where $m$ is the number of sets in $\mathcal{F}$. Since the rows of $A$ are indicator vectors, $a_{ij} = 1$ if the i-th set in $\mathcal{F}$ contains the natural number $j$ and $a_{ij} = 0$ if the i-th set in $\mathcal{F}$ does not contain the natural number $j$.

Matrix $A$ is totally unimodular if for every square submatrix $B$ of $A$, we have that $\det B \in\{-1,0,1\}$. It makes at lot of sense that $\det B\in\{-1,0,1\}$, because we have $b_{ij} \in\{0,1\}$, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

**Question:** How do I show that matrix $A$ is totally unimodular?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I thought it made a lot of sense for $\det B\in\{-1,0,1\}$ just because $b_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$, but apparently this is not so self evident. There's another exercise in my book where I again have to show that $A$ is totally unimodular, but now the rows of $A$ are the characteristic vectors of $\mathcal{F}_1\cup\mathcal{F}_2$, where $\mathcal{F}_1, \mathcal{F}_2$ are nested families of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Even though the elements of a square submatrix $B$ would be in $\{0,1\}$, the exercise is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $B$ be a square submatrix. The rows of $B$ also define a nested family of sets $B_i$. Choose any row, $i$, which is minimal in this family, so that for every other row  $j$, either $B_i$ is either a subset of $B_j$ or disjoint with $B_j$.

Use elementary row operations to clear all the ones in $B$ which share a column with any $1$ in row $i$, then use cofactor expansion along any column which intersects row $i$ at a $1$, then proceed by induction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your approach does work indeed! However, regarding the edit I made; wouldn't your approach work on the second case as well?

Comment: Yes, but it is not quite as easy. The square submatrix $B$ has two types of rows, corresponding to sets in $\mathcal F_1$ and $\mathcal F_2$. You can only use row operations between two rows of the same type if you want to preserve the structure of the problem. This means you can't proceed by induction.

Comment: I can see what you mean. Do you know how I should handle the case $\mathcal{F}_1\cup\mathcal{F}_2$?

Comment: Sorry, I do not. You should probably ask that as a separate question.